# How to convert a JSON array to an array of string values

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm try to parse some JSON like this:

```
{
   "results": [
       "MLU413843206",
       "MLU413841098",
       "MLU413806325",
       "MLU413850890",
       "MLU413792303",
       "MLU413843455",
       "MLU413909270",
       "MLU413921617",
       "MLU413921983",
       "MLU413924015",
       "MLU413924085"
   ]
}
```

All is fine until I try to obtain the values themselves, for example:

```
 // The JSON is shown above
 var jsonResp = JObject.Parse(json);    
 var items = jsonResp["results"].Children();
```

I don't know how to obtain the values, each converted to string.  Does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: The JSON you're trying to parse is not valid. Between the key and the value there should not be a minus symbol.

Comment: you should learn json structure first. Means how one json object structure is

Comment: This looks correct, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: What I need is obtain the text inside this JSON using JSON.NET , I have obtained this using another techniques with string parsing, etc. But I don't want do it in this way. I want a elegant way using JSON.NET in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there.  You can use the `Select()` method in the `System.Linq` namespace to project the `IEnumerable<JToken>` returned from the `Children()` method into an `IEnumerable<string>`.  From there you can loop over the values using `foreach`, or put the values into a `List<string>` using `ToList()` (or both).

```
string json = @"
{
    ""results"": [
        ""MLU413843206"",
        ""MLU413841098"",
        ""MLU413806325"",
        ""MLU413850890"",
        ""MLU413792303"",
        ""MLU413843455"",
        ""MLU413909270"",
        ""MLU413921617"",
        ""MLU413921983"",
        ""MLU413924015"",
        ""MLU413924085""
    ]
}";

JObject jsonResp = JObject.Parse(json);
List<string> items = jsonResp["results"].Children()
                                        .Select(t => t.ToString())
                                        .ToList();
foreach (string item in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jcy8Ao